# Woocommerce | Export Order Items to JSON | External API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, integration

**Scenraio:** using woocommerce and am required to serialize the order object and send to external api. 
**Issue:** Unable to get the JSON of items in the order.

```
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    $items = $order->get_items();
```

I tried the following:

1. The `implode($items);` method returns the JSON but it has escaped quotes and does not separate the array items by a ",".
2. Tried `foreach` on `$items` to add each item to another array `array_push($order_items,$item);` but `json_encode($order_items);` return an array of `nulls`

Is there a way to inspect each property of the `$item` and assign it to a custom object, create an array and the serialize the same array?

PHP NOOB.

Comment: Did you initialize the `$order_items` array before foreach? Then `$order_items = array();`.

Comment: I didn't initially, but after i added the initialization, it didn't make any difference

Comment: Could you publish the entire code you have tested so far?